# Remove duplicates based on multi column and keep latest entry in google sheets using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet like this structure

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmYuq.png)

I want to remove remove duplicates based on multi column and keep latest entry, so result I want like this

[table_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i5GW.png)

I have tried with this function, but latest entry removed.

````
function removeDuplicates() {
  function removeDuplicates() {
  var checkHeadeTitles = ["School Name", "Class Name", "Group Name"]; // Duplicate based this header.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var header = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var columnNumber = checkHeadeTitles.map(e => {
    var idx = header.indexOf(e);
    if (idx == -1) {
      throw new Error(`No header tilte of '${e}'.`);
    }
    return idx + 1;
  });
  sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).removeDuplicates(columnNumber);

  var row = sh.getDataRange().getValues().findIndex(r => r.join("") == "");
  if (row == -1) return;
  sh.deleteRow(row + 1);
}
}```

Please help me.
Thank you
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- About `I have tried with this function, but latest entry removed.`, in the current stage, it seems that this situation is the current specification of `removeDuplicates`. When `removeDuplicates` is used, it seems that the duplicate rows are removed while the top row is kept.

In order to achieve your goal, how about the following modifications?

#### Modified script 1:

In this modification, the values that removed the duplicate rows and the empty rows are created and the created values are put into the cells.

```js
function removeDuplicates1() {
  var checkHeadeTitles = ["School Name", "Class Name", "Group Name"]; // Duplicate based this header.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range = sh.getDataRange();
  var [header, ...values] = range.getValues();
  var index = checkHeadeTitles.map(e => {
    var idx = header.indexOf(e);
    if (idx == -1) {
      throw new Error(`No header tilte of '${e}'.`);
    }
    return idx;
  });
  var v = [...values.reverse().reduce((m, r) => {
    var k = index.map(e => r[e]).join("");
    if (k && !m.has(k)) {
      m.set(k, r);
    }
    return m;
  }, new Map()).values()].reverse();
  range.offset(1, 0).clearContent().offset(0, 0, v.length, v[0].length).setValues(v);
}
```

- In this case, the process cost is low. But, when you want to keep the text styles of each row, this modification cannot be used.

#### Modified script 2:

In this modification, the removed the duplicate rows are removed.

```js
function removeDuplicates2() {
  var checkHeadeTitles = ["School Name", "Class Name", "Group Name"]; // Duplicate based this header.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var [header, ...values] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var index = checkHeadeTitles.map(e => {
    var idx = header.indexOf(e);
    if (idx == -1) {
      throw new Error(`No header tilte of '${e}'.`);
    }
    return idx;
  });
  var { rows } = values.reverse().reduce((o, r, i, a) => {
    var k = index.map(e => r[e]).join("");
    if (k && !o.s.has(k)) {
      o.s.add(k);
    } else {
      o.rows.push(a.length - i + 1);
    }
    return o;
  }, { s: new Set(), rows: [] });
  if (rows.length == 0) return;
  rows.forEach(e => sh.deleteRow(e));
}
```

- In this case, the process cost is high. But, when you want to keep the text styles of rows, this modification can be used.
- When you want to reduce the process cost, I think that Sheets API can be used for this situation. In that case, please modify this script as follows. And, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

  - From

    ```js
    rows.forEach(e => sh.deleteRow(e));
    ```
  - To

    ```js
    var sheetId = sh.getSheetId();
    var requests = rows.map(e => ({ deleteDimension: { range: { sheetId, startIndex: e - 1, endIndex: e, dimension: "ROWS" } } }));
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ss.getId());
    ```

#### References:

- [removeDuplicates(columnsToCompare)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#removeduplicatescolumnstocompare)
- [deleteRow(rowPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowrowposition)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Modification script is running well as I need.

Comment: @fauzi Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.